# More than 1 local database - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have this basic question that I can't resolve with Stack & Google. Is it possible to create more than one local DB on a laptop? I use MySQL and I already have one local db (127.0.0.1, 3306), but it's reserved for another learning project. I really don't want to risk losing it.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

No problem you just create another database using

```
Create database “your database name”
```

and use this new database to your new application and It’s not affect your old application running in the same machine